Summation of a tensor is giving -inf as output even though no element has -inf value in it
The size of tensor is [4,884736].
I am doing the summation with torch.sum(dim=1)
I have checked whether the tensor has float(‘-inf’) value with :-
1] torch.where(tensor == float(‘-inf’), 1, 0) → count the non_zero → output is zero
2] torch.where(tensor < -7, 1, 0) → count the non_zero → output is zero. Thus indicating that no element is lesser than -7
3] tensor[tensor == float(‘-inf’)] == 0. Still the result is -inf.
